# Can't get my database in Sqlite3 to accept text

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I have a python program that is trying to write an entry to a database.  The code successfully executes, and the entry in the sales table is created, but when I examine the database in DB Browser for SQLite, it shows that the text columns are blank.  Here is the relevant sections of code:

```
class SDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("sales.db")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales (orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, customer TEXT, itemPurchased TEXT)")
        self.conn.commit()

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def view(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sales")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def search(self, customer="", itemPurchased=""):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE customer=? OR itemPurchased=?", (customer, itemPurchased,))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def purchase(self, customer, itemPurchased):
        orderID=randint(1000, 9999)
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO sales (orderID, customer, itemPurchased) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (orderID, customer, itemPurchased,))
        self.conn.commit()
        print("Order Placed!")
```

sbd = SDB()

This is the database definition in python, and the function **purchase** gets called by a tkinter window:

```
purchase_window = tk.Tk()
    purchase_window.title('Purchase Books')
    window_width = 300
    window_height = 200
    screen_width = purchase_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = purchase_window.winfo_screenheight()
    center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
    purchase_window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
    
    itemLabel = ttk.Label(purchase_window, text="Book Title")
    itemEntry = ttk.Entry(purchase_window)
    customerLabel = ttk.Label(purchase_window, text="Your Name")
    customerEntry = ttk.Entry(purchase_window)
    
    itemPurchased = itemEntry.get()
    customer = customerEntry.get()
    orderButton = ttk.Button(purchase_window, text="Purchase", command=sbd.purchase(customer, itemPurchased))
    
    itemLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    itemEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    customerLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
    customerEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    orderButton.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

As you can see, the code is supposed to insert the customer name, the name of the book they ordered, and a randomly generated order ID.  The order ID is inserted into the database just fine, but the text items don't.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

- using result of `random.randint()` for `orderID` column may cause duplicate error, use `AUTOINCREMENT` feature on `orderID` column instead

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales (orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, customer TEXT, itemPurchased TEXT)
```

- you get the content of `itemEntry` and `customerEntry` just after they are created and so `itemPurchased` and `customer` are empty strings due to no input yet.  You need to call those `.get()` inside `sbd.purchase()` instead

```py
def purchase(self):
    # get the required content from entries
    customer = customerEntry.get()
    itemPurchased = itemEntry.get()
    # removed orderID as it is an autoincrement column now
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO sales (customer, itemPurchased) VALUES (?, ?)", (customer, itemPurchased))
    self.conn.commit()
    print("Order Placed!")
```

- `command=sbd.purchase(customer, itemPurchased)` will execute `sbd.purchase()` immediately, not on button click.  Use `command=sbd.purchase` and redefine `sbd.purchase()` without arguments as above.

```py
orderButton = ttk.Button(purchase_window, text="Purchase", command=sbd.purchase)
```